# I'm getting a negative values as output of Iterative Imputer and used list of min and max values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, iteration

I'm using a Multiple Imputer from sklearn library to impute some missing values. I was able to run the IterativeImputer and get an output with all my missing values filled. The problem is that the output contains negative values. I tried to give a list of min and max values but it throwing up the error.I have tried giving an array of min and max values with column names.

```
minimun_before = df_sample.iloc[:,:].min(axis=0)


maximum_before = df_sample.iloc[:,:].max(axis=0)

imputer_data = IterativeImputer(random_state = 0, skip_complete=True,sample_posterior=True, max_iter = 10, missing_values = np.nan,verbose=2, min_value = min_list, max_value=max_list )
```

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,) (31,)
```

can you please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imp = IterativeImputer(random_state = 0, skip_complete=True,sample_posterior=True, 
max_iter = 10, missing_values = np.nan,verbose=2, min_value = min_list, ` 
max_value=max_list )`
imp.fit(df_sample)

imputed_data = pd.DataFrame(data=imp.transform(df_sample))
imputed_data.describe()
```

Comment: it did not work, same error. I think it is not taking list or array, i have also looked into the github it says it allows array or list
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,) (31,)

Comment: the above code works, it just the sklearn package update will resolve the problem.

Comment: If it is work, if i ask, can you approve the answer :)